# Are Hibernate's callbacks asynchronous?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, database-performance, hibernate-5.x

I have gone through below link and implemented hibernate interceptors. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks

It is said in document @PrePersist, @PreRemove and @PostRemove are synchronous.

- Are all other callbacks asynchronous?
- Is there any way to make above callbacks asynchronous?

Comment: Hard to believe when JDBC is (until fresh new standard) synchronous